# How to search pattern in pdf file without itexsharp iby powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search a pattern by reading pdf file, I used `Select-String` command but its not worked.

How do I search in a pdf without using [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp)?

Comment: you cannot do that. powershell has NO native ability to read the text of normal PDF files.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, is there any possibility to search pattern in pdf files Through batchscript?

Comment: the BAT/CMD method would [just as with powershell] require a utility to process the PDF file. that file type is NOT normally readable by anything other than a PDF reader. you will require something similar to the `iTextSharp` code to process the content of a PDF file.

Comment: I would imagine by now that in 2022 someone figured out how to write a ps1 file that install-module the right library and just does the thing. nope? no one? I've spent 20-30 mins looking for this. a bit bewildered by this community.

Answer (score 0):

Three years ago...I'm searching how to insert pages to PDF file without iTextSharp and found this question.

I'm not able to use iTextSharp so I normally convert PDF to text file and then get information from the text file using PowerShell only. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).